# How to set ENT_QUOTES flag by default for htmlentities() function in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-entities

I am using `htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES)` on any data fetched from database before displaying it.

Is there a way I can set the flag `ENT_QUOTES` by default for `htmlentities()` function, so that even if I write `htmlentities($data)` it should work as `htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES)`.

As written in the documentation of php the default is `ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401`.

For your information I am using codeigniter framework, php5.

UPDATE 1: wrapping with a custom function as suggested by Michael could help but I have already used this everywhere in the website without ENT_QUOTES flag and was wondering if there is a way provided by php to change defaults for its functions.

UPDATE 2: I think html_escape() inbuilt function provided by codeigniter (suggested by Wesley) is the best for me so that i don't have to write my own wrapper function.

Comment: Why do you use `htmlentities`, not `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: You could just wrap the function.  `function my_htmlentities($string) {return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES);}` and call `my_htmlentities()` instead.

Comment: @zerkms Maybe commonly using it inside HTML attributes, where `htmlentities()` handles quote encoding in a more straight-forward way.

Comment: @Zerkms: It doesn't make a difference as far as this problem is concerned, because for htmlspecialchars as well I need to provide ENT_QUOTES flag.. right?

Comment: @Michael: Wrapping the function is of course a good hack and it should work.. I'll try it out :) 
but is there a more basic approach as well like changing some ini etc.

Comment: @AnkitPrasad I don't think there is any way to modify the default behavior - that's why I suggested the hack.

Comment: There was a language fork called "php infusion" which enabled that option per default. But recompiling your version and changing the option yourself isn't difficult. However, a wrapper function is the way to go here. It's not hacky. It's what you ought to do in a hybrid language. Also name it less clumsy: the more frequently used the shorter a function name should be. Easing secure usage is the prerequisite for thorough security.

Comment: @AnkitPrasad Since you have already used `htmlentities()` without ENT_QUOTES, wrapping the function may be your best option. It is then just a simple string replacement to substitute the wrapper function across your code base, and when you need to use it with other flags or in its default state, you can keep using `htmlentities()` instead of the wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to change the default flags that I know of, but the advice given to you in the comments is absolutely the best way to approach this anyways: use a wrapper function.

Conveniently, Codeigniter has one built in already, appropriately named:

```
echo html_escape($string);
```

You can pass in arrays as well, here's what it does:

```
/**
* Returns HTML escaped variable
*
* @access   public
* @param    mixed
* @return   mixed
*/
if ( ! function_exists('html_escape'))
{
    function html_escape($var)
    {
        if (is_array($var))
        {
            return array_map('html_escape', $var);
        }
        else
        {
            return htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, config_item('charset'));
        }
    }
}
```

Just do a search for `htmlentities` in your project and replace (carefully) with `html_escape`. This will also provide the opportunity for you to easily make changes in the future because you can alter the function. It's a little bit of an initial time investment but well worth it.

Comment: The fact that it can clean arrays as well has made my life a lot easier.. I just have to pass the complete data array at once in the controller itself before sending it to view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the variable directly. 
For example:
$this->model_name->variable;

Then you can use __get function in model name and process it before it is accesses from object.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Comment: I didn't get it.. how is it solving my purpose?